# JSON with variable key in bash

Tags: bash, json

In the bash script below, I have JSON object and need to have key `hostname` with random name, like `host-$NAME` (i.e. `host-1`, `host-3`). How to do it ?

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME=($(( ( RANDOM % 10 )  + 1 )))
OUTPUT='{
  "hostname": "host-$NAME",
  "plan": "baremetal_0",               
  "operating_system": "coreos_stable"
}'

echo $OUTPUT
```

The script output is below

```
$ ./packet-ask.sh 
{ "hostname": "host-$NAME", "plan": "baremetal_0", "operating_system": "coreos_stable" }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
OUTPUT='{
  "hostname": "host-'$NAME'",
...
```

Comment: In general, this is a rally bad suggestion as `$NAME` may contain characters that needs to be encoded before included in the JSON document. Also, this solution solves the issue by leaving the `$NAME` expansion totally unquoted, which is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @Kusalananda As seen in line 2 of the script, `$NAME` is only going to contain digits.

Comment: Is there any _harm_ in doing it correctly? You are actually leaving an expansion of a shell variable totally unquoted even though it would be _easy_ to remedy this. See e.g. [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171347)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the shell does not expand variables inside single-quoted strings.  A minor other thing is that your `NAME` variable actually happens to be an *array* due to the way you assign the value to it (`NAME=(...)`).  You also use your `OUTPUT` variable unquoted (which would split its contents on white-spaces and apply filename globbing to all the generated words) and with `echo` (which may, under some circumstances, modify the data that it's outputting).

Consider adopting safer ways of creating JSON documents.  It is not *always* possible to inject a shell string into a JSON document.  In this particular case, it ought to be fairly safe, but you generally want to use a tool that knows how to handle characters like quotes and newlines properly.

Using [`jo`](https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/) to create the JSON document:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

printf -v name 'host-%s' "$(( 1 + (RANDOM % 10) ))"

jo hostname="$name" plan='baremetal_0' operating_system='coreos_stable'
```

Using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to do the same thing:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

printf -v name 'host-%s' "$(( 1 + (RANDOM % 10) ))"

jq -n -c --arg name "$name" \
    '{ "hostname": $name, "plan": "baremetal_0", "operating_system": "coeros_stable" }'
```

Note that in both these cases,

1. The string `$name` is properly JSON encoded.  This matters since it's possible that one at some later point decides that `$name` should be some other random string that may need encoding.
2. The output from `jo`/`jq` is not saved in a shell variable.  This is not needed since we're just interested in outputting the generated JSON document.